# Why does this give me a red wire in Logisim?

Tags: digital-logic, wiring, logisim

[image: Logisim wiring diagram]

Why does this gives me a red wire? Is it a bug? I'm pretty sure my wirings are correct.

Comment: Your tool treats combinational loop as an error.

Comment: Look [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/439211/38098), for example. Logisim gives red whenever there are problems with bus width or with astable circuitry, I think.You've got what looks like the astable kind of error here, as @Light says.

Comment: Ok nice ill check on that thanks for the help guys!

Answer (score 2):

Most probably you reset the simulation, but you have no running clock.

So the NORs get `0` on one of their inputs, and `ERROR` on the other, since their default output value is this. As long as this does not change, the NORs cannot output any other value, because `0` OR `ERROR` is still `ERROR`.

Start the clock via the menu "Simulate" - "Ticks enabled" or Ctrl-K.

As soon as one of a NOR's input becomes `1`, its output will be `0`, too. And the first R-S flip-flop will be error-free. In the second clock phase the second R-S flip-flop will be error-free.

You can watch this step-by-step if you let the clock tick just once. See the menu or type Ctrl-T.

*Note: This is not a bug in Logisim, nor in your circuit. Actually I would expect this behavior.*

Comment: Ok great appreciated! When I put my clock to high it works completely fine (the red wires turn green). However whenever I restart my logisim the red wires reappear.

Comment: Before writing my answer, I rebuilt your circuit in Logisim, and it works as described. Do you have any changes in your circuit?

Comment: I believe it's actually undefined (blue), unless you turn on the option to treat undefined as error.

Comment: I had pretty much the same problem with an SR  flip flop , I made 2 versions of it one with the basic gates and another out of the gates embedded in a 74HC00 IC simulated in logisim and had the same issue with the oscillation error but enabling ticks fixed that for me :)     If you keep getting the oscillation error that stops the circuit simulation even when you know your circuit is correct you can go into the project - options menu and set   iterations  until oscillation at 50000.